# Cambio del tamaño del array en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c, string

quería saber que sucede cuando escribo una palabra menor a 100 caracteres:

```
char cad[100];

printf("Cadena: ");

scanf("%s", cad);
```

ya que usando `strlen()` pude verificar que se cambia el tamaño del array.

Ahora la pregunta es: ¿Que sucede con esa memoria que ya no se va a utilizar, por ejemplo cuando se pasa de un arreglo de tamaño 100 a un arreglo de tamaño 5? ¿Se libera esa memoria? ¿esto lo hace el sistema operativo o como es?

Comment: `strlen()` no te da el tamaño del array, sino la longitud de la cadena que hayas introducido en ese array. El tamaño del array lo obtienes con `sizeof(cad)`, y verás que ese no cambia.

Comment: Una cadena de caracteres en C no es más que una secuencia de bytes (los códigos ascii de las letras que componen la cadena), más un byte final de valor `0` que indica que ya no hay más caracteres. `strlen()` simplemente cuenta cuántos bytes encuentra hasta llegar al que vale 0. Lo que haya más allá de ese byte ya no lo mira. Cuando lees un texto con `scanf("%s")` esta función va leyendo de la entrada estándar caracteres hasta encontrar un espacio o retorno de carro y los va dejando en la dirección que le pases. Al final añade el 0 terminador.

Comment: Entonces estaría desperdiciando memoria al utilizar solamente algunos espacios del array y no todos. ¿Como creo una buena declaración de un array para no desperdiciar memoria?

Resulta que tengo entendido que si declaro un puntero igualmente debo declararlo así:

char *cadena = New char[100];

lo que me estaría igualmente desperdiciando memoria de la misma manera, no?

Comment: El problema es que no sabes de antemano cuántos caracteres va a teclear el usuario. El problema que planteas no tiene solución sencilla. Deberías declarar un puntero a `char` y reservar espacio (digamos por ejemplo 100 caracteres) con `malloc(100)`. Una vez leída la respuesta del usuario puedes hacer un `realloc()` para reducir el tamaño reservado. El verdadero problema es ¿y si la respuesta del usuario tenía más de 100 caracteres? En ese caso `scanf()` almacenaría la respuesta incluso más allá de la zona reservada (y eso es un buffer overrun) (sigue...)

Comment: (...sigue) Por esa razón `scanf("%s")` se considera inseguro, al igual que `gets()` y se recomienda en cambio usar `fgets()` para leer cadenas, ya que esta última tiene un parámetro que especifica cuántos caracteres leer como máximo, asegurándote asi de que no incurres en un buffer overrun. Si el usuario teclea más de 100, el resto quedan sin leer. Siempre puedes hacer un `realloc()` para aumentar el buffer, seguido de otro `fgets()` para leer lo que quede, etc. Pero como digo no hay solución sencilla.

Comment: Lo que suele hacerse en definitiva es declarar un array estático de un tamaño suficiente para la máxima cantidad de texto que razonablemente el usuario pudiera meter, usar `fgets()` para leer el texto asegurándote de que no se producirá el overrun, y despreocuparse del "desperdicio" de memoria si el usuario introduce menos de ese máximo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> quería saber que sucede cuando escribo una palabra menor a 100 caracteres

En el ejemplo que has puesto no sucede nada malo. Has declarado un array con espacio para almacenar hasta 100 caracteres. Si tu intención es almacenar en dicho array una cadena de texto podrás almacenar hasta 99 caracteres (recuerda que en C las cadenas deben con `\0`, que ocupa una posición).

Mientras no superes la longitud de 99 caracteres tu programa va a funcionar, al menos en ese punto, correctamente.

> ya que usando strlen() pude verificar que se cambia el tamaño del array.

En esto te estás confundiendo. `strlen` es una función que indica la **longiutd de la cadena** almacenada... no la longitud del array. Ese array que has declarado es de tamaño fijo y, como es de esperar, su tamaño no puede ser modificado de ninguna forma en tiempo de ejecución.

Puedes verificar como el tamaño del array no cambia usando `sizeof` (el ejemplo no va a funcionar con arrays dinámicos):

```
char cad[100];
printf("size: %d\n",sizeof(cad));

printf("Cadena: ");

scanf("%s", cad);
printf("size: %d\n",sizeof(cad));
```

> ¿Que sucede con esa memoria que ya no se va a utilizar, por ejemplo cuando se pasa de un arreglo de tamaño 100 a un arreglo de tamaño 5?

Pasa que no se usa... se desaprovecha. Normalmente no pasa nada ya que el sistema suele tener recursos de sobra... pero hay que tener cuidado porque si te excedes entonces el programa fallará antes o después al quedarse el sistema sin recursos.

Si necesitas un ajuste más fino, que te permita adaptarte a las necesidades de cada momento tienes que cambiar a arrays de tamaño dinámico. La memoria dinámica es mucho más flexible pero también te exige controlar su ciclo de vida.

> ¿Se libera esa memoria?

Ya has visto que no. El array que has declarado se almacena en la pila del programa y esa memoria se liberará automáticamente cuando la variable se salga de ámbito.

En cambio, si el array fuese dinámico es necesario llamar a `free` para liberar la memoria y no crear fugas de memoria.

> ¿esto lo hace el sistema operativo o como es?

La memoria de la pila la controla directamente la aplicación. En el caso de arrays de tamaño fijo no te preocupes por la gestión de la memoria ya que poco puedes hacer al respecto.

Comment: pero  si declaro un puntero igualmente debo declararlo así: char *cadena = New char[100]; lo que me estaría igualmente desperdiciando memoria de la misma manera, no? ya que crea un puntero a un espacio de 100 bytes el cual seguramente no utilice todo. Es lo mismo que haber creado el array sin punteros.

o de que manera debería utilizar los punteros dices?

Comment: @Edu new (en minúsculas) es c++, no c. Un puntero creado con `malloc` se puede redimensionar con `realloc`. El problema de los arrays de tamaño fijo es que la pila tiene mucha menos capacidad que la disponible para el caso dinámico

Comment: @Edu en cualquier caso piensa que un array de tamaño  fijo declarado en una función libera su memoria cuando el programa abandona la función

Comment: Perdón, es que estoy utilizando C pero con new y delete y nada mas que eso de C++. Y cómo sería entonces sin usar malloc o realloc para no desperdiciar memoria en un array? Se que al terminar la función es liberado, pero quiero saber como no desperdiciar memoria en cada momento posible. Lo mas eficiente posible.

Comment: @Edu si usas `new` o `delete` entonces estas programando en c++... te guste o no. Aunque tengan cosas en común son lenguajes diferentes... en serio no te agobies por la memoria... un equipo medio de hoy en día tiene al menos 4GB de memoria

Comment: bueno dale! entendido. Estuve pensandolo y si quiero realmente ahorrar la máxima memoria posible debería crear mis propia lista de caracteres con punteros no? e ir generando nuevo espacio de memoria a medida que lo vaya necesitando, sin olvidarme de siempre liberar la memoria al finalizar el uso de la lista. No?

Comment: @Edu si afinas demasiado veras que el programa se vuelve lento porque la gestión de la memoria es un proceso pesado... es mejor encontrar un equilibrio... aunque ya lo descubrirás con el tiempo